# Character with the 殳 radical

Tags: characters

What is the character in the picture below:

[image]

I did not find it in the index of [殳](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E6%AE%B3)

Comment: according to 现代汉语词典（１９９８年）：  **般 ^1**    sort; kind; class; way; manner，belongs to radical  舟 (see answers)， **股^２**   同＇搬＇另见９５页bo１；９４８页pan２ belongs to radical  殳 (other examples  殳、殴、殁、段)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [般](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%88%AC) (bān).

Note that its 部首 (radical) is [舟](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Chinese_radical/%E8%88%9F).

Answer (score 0):

般 bān. I believe it's belong to index of 舟